# Make recent post display recent updated, instead of recent published

Tags: posts, query-posts

Is there a way to show posts in the order of recent updated, instead of recent published? Is there a plugin to hook the internal query function, so that I don't need to make changes in template file?

Comment: I would look at `pre_get_posts` hook, and `WP_Query` object's orderby param.

Comment: I just found this plugin, not exactly what I want, but serve the same purpose: http://www.magatsu.net/randomosity/wordpress-plugin-auto-update-date/